# shell_exec in php stil working after disconect?

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

How does the shell_exec work in php? when I disconect the browser connection to the server, will the shell_exec continue working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php process will be terminated when the client closes the connection unless you use ignore_user_abort(1);

Also, the process needs to send something to the client to check if he is still connected. A process that has no output may continue to run after the client disconnects.

To execute a command in the background and keep it running after the php process ends, use something like this:

```
exec($cmd.' > /dev/null &');
```

Comment: tank you . iam using  
    `2>&1 | tee result.txt` in end of command
he is still connected?

Comment: Do you need the output to be returned to the php process? If not, use $cmd.' > result.txt &